# Make radial lines that run in and join each other for grid cells PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

So I have this grid

[image]

and I want to make radial lines that come out of the centroid of each of the grid cells like spokes. lets say I want there to be 8 spokes. The spokes from one grid cell should line up and join with the spokes of the surrounding cells, I would also like to join ones that line up and intersect.

So far my attempt is to buffer out each grid cell by the amount I want so the resulting lines are long enough (I use 300 meters) and then I connect the opposite corners of these larger grid cells, and the opposite midpoints of the sides (and then between the midpoint and corners if I want to get up to 8 spokes)
here is an example with 4 spokes:

```
        drop table if exists squarepoints;
    create temp table squarepoints as select (st_buffer(poly::geography, 300, 'join=mitre'))::geometry as geom,id from test_final; -- poly from test_final is the grid cell geometry
    CREATE INDEX on squarepoints USING GiST (geom);
    drop table if exists pre_qgis_combine_1;
    create temp table pre_qgis_combine_1 as select st_makeline(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 1), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 3)) as nl from squarepoints;
    select * from pre_qgis_combine_1;
    drop table if exists pre_qgis_combine_2;
    create temp table pre_qgis_combine_2 as select st_makeline(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 2), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 4)) as nl from squarepoints;
    select * from pre_qgis_combine_2;
    drop table if exists pre_qgis_combine_3;
    create temp table pre_qgis_combine_3 as select st_makeline((ST_LineInterpolatePoint((st_makeline(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 1), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 2))), 0.5)),
                                                           (ST_LineInterpolatePoint((st_makeline(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 3), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 4))), 0.5))) as nl from squarepoints;
    select * from pre_qgis_combine_3;
    drop table if exists pre_qgis_combine_4;
    create temp table pre_qgis_combine_4 as select st_makeline((ST_LineInterpolatePoint((st_makeline(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 2), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 3))), 0.5)),
                                                           (ST_LineInterpolatePoint((st_makeline(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 1), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 4))), 0.5))) as nl from squarepoints;
    select * from pre_qgis_combine_4;
    
    drop table if exists qgis_combine_1;
    create temp table qgis_combine_1 as SELECT 1 as origin_table, ST_LongestLine((ST_CollectionExtract(unnest(ST_ClusterIntersecting(nl)))), (ST_CollectionExtract(unnest(ST_ClusterIntersecting(nl))))) as nl from pre_qgis_combine_1;
    CREATE INDEX on qgis_combine_1 USING GiST (nl);
    drop table if exists qgis_combine_2;
    create temp table qgis_combine_2 as SELECT 2 as origin_table, ST_LongestLine((ST_CollectionExtract(unnest(ST_ClusterIntersecting(nl)))), (ST_CollectionExtract(unnest(ST_ClusterIntersecting(nl))))) as nl from pre_qgis_combine_2;
    CREATE INDEX on qgis_combine_2 USING GiST (nl);
    drop table if exists qgis_combine_3;
    create temp table qgis_combine_3 as SELECT 3 as origin_table, ST_LongestLine((ST_CollectionExtract(unnest(ST_ClusterIntersecting(nl)))), (ST_CollectionExtract(unnest(ST_ClusterIntersecting(nl))))) as nl from pre_qgis_combine_3;
    CREATE INDEX on qgis_combine_3 USING GiST (nl);
    drop table if exists qgis_combine_4;
    create temp table qgis_combine_4 as SELECT 4 as origin_table, ST_LongestLine((ST_CollectionExtract(unnest(ST_ClusterIntersecting(nl)))), (ST_CollectionExtract(unnest(ST_ClusterIntersecting(nl))))) as nl from pre_qgis_combine_4;
    CREATE INDEX on qgis_combine_4 USING GiST (nl);
    drop table if exists linesss;
    create temp table linesss as 
    select sq.origin_table, sq.nl as nl, st_srid(sq.nl) from (select origin_table, nl, row_number() OVER (order by 1) as id from qgis_combine_1 NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN qgis_combine_2 NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN qgis_combine_3 NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN qgis_combine_4)
     sq group by sq.id, sq.origin_table, sq.nl order by sq.origin_table;
    select * from linesss;
```

the grid geometry is here (but ideally the solution would work for the general case):

```
"POLYGON((-117.20051364777042 53.33216281080787,-117.20033813419441 53.33304439629491,-117.19886541384653 53.3327511945368,-117.19904092742254 53.33186960904976,-117.20051364777042 53.33216281080787))"
"POLYGON((-117.19904092742254 53.33186960904976,-117.19886541384653 53.3327511945368,-117.19739269349866 53.332457992778686,-117.19756820707467 53.33157640729165,-117.19904092742254 53.33186960904976))"
"POLYGON((-117.20033813419441 53.33304439629491,-117.2001626206184 53.33392598178193,-117.19868990027052 53.33363278002382,-117.19886541384653 53.3327511945368,-117.20033813419441 53.33304439629491))"
"POLYGON((-117.19886541384653 53.3327511945368,-117.19868990027052 53.33363278002382,-117.19721717992265 53.33333957826572,-117.19739269349866 53.332457992778686,-117.19886541384653 53.3327511945368))"
"POLYGON((-117.19739269349866 53.332457992778686,-117.19721717992265 53.33333957826572,-117.19574445957477 53.33304637650761,-117.19591997315078 53.33216479102059,-117.19739269349866 53.332457992778686))"
```

My result *looks* okay, but if you zoom in you can see the lines don't actually join up when they should.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use this string of queries to successfully get the radial lines and they're grouped together by azimuth:

```
        drop table if exists pre_qgis_combine_1;
    create temp table pre_qgis_combine_1 as select cell, st_snap(st_makeline(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 1), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 3)), st_collect(centroid.cen), 0.000001) as nl from squarepoints, centroid group by cell, geom;
    drop table if exists pre_qgis_combine_2;
    create temp table pre_qgis_combine_2 as select cell, st_snap(st_makeline(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 2), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 4)), st_collect(centroid.cen), 0.000001) as nl from squarepoints, centroid group by cell, geom;
    drop table if exists pre_qgis_combine_3;
    create temp table pre_qgis_combine_3 as select cell, st_snap(st_makeline((ST_LineInterpolatePoint((st_makeline(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 1), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 2))), 0.5)),
                                                (ST_LineInterpolatePoint((st_makeline(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 3), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 4))), 0.5))), st_collect(centroid.cen), 0.000001) as nl from squarepoints, centroid group by cell, geom;
    drop table if exists pre_qgis_combine_4;
    create temp table pre_qgis_combine_4 as select cell, st_snap(st_makeline((ST_LineInterpolatePoint((st_makeline(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 2), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 3))), 0.5)),
                                                (ST_LineInterpolatePoint((st_makeline(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 1), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 4))), 0.5))), st_collect(centroid.cen), 0.000001)  as nl from squarepoints, centroid group by cell, geom;
    drop table if exists pre_qgis_combine_5;
    create temp table pre_qgis_combine_5 as select cell, st_snap(st_makeline((ST_LineInterpolatePoint((st_makeline(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 1), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 2))), 0.25)),
                                                (ST_LineInterpolatePoint((st_makeline(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 3), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 4))), 0.25))), st_collect(centroid.cen), 0.000001)  as nl from squarepoints, centroid group by cell, geom;                                  
    drop table if exists pre_qgis_combine_6;
    create temp table pre_qgis_combine_6 as select cell, st_snap(st_makeline((ST_LineInterpolatePoint((st_makeline(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 2), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 3))), 0.25)),
                                                (ST_LineInterpolatePoint((st_makeline(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 4), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 1))), 0.25))), st_collect(centroid.cen), 0.000001)  as nl from squarepoints, centroid group by cell, geom;
    drop table if exists pre_qgis_combine_7;
    create temp table pre_qgis_combine_7 as select cell, st_snap(st_makeline((ST_LineInterpolatePoint((st_makeline(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 1), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 2))), 0.75)),
                                                (ST_LineInterpolatePoint((st_makeline(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 3), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 4))), 0.75))), st_collect(centroid.cen), 0.000001)  as nl from squarepoints, centroid group by cell, geom;
    drop table if exists pre_qgis_combine_8;
    create temp table pre_qgis_combine_8 as select cell, st_snap(st_makeline((ST_LineInterpolatePoint((st_makeline(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 2), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 3))), 0.75)),
                                                (ST_LineInterpolatePoint((st_makeline(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 4), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 1))), 0.75))), st_collect(centroid.cen), 0.000001)  as nl from squarepoints, centroid group by cell, geom;
```

I'm using snap to snap to a table of points so that the lines of the same azimuth that run into each other will effectively join together.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly this is one way to solve your question.

Create a Geo-spatial function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_RaysInGridPolygons(
geom GEOMETRY
)
RETURNS TABLE (geom GEOMETRY) AS
$BODY$
WITH
    tbla AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as id, (ST_Dump(geom)).geom),
    tblb AS (SELECT id, ST_Boundary(geom) geom FROM tbla),
    tblc AS (SELECT id, ST_MakeLine(pt1, pt2) geom FROM (SELECT id, ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(geom)-1)) pt1,
          ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(2, ST_NPoints(geom))) pt2 FROM tblb) AS geom),
    tbld AS (SELECT id, ST_Centroid(geom) geom FROM tblc UNION SELECT id, (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom geom FROM tblb),
    tble AS (SELECT id bid, ST_Centroid(geom) geom FROM tbla), 
    tblf AS (SELECT bid, ST_MakeLine(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM tble a 
                 CROSS JOIN (SELECT id, (geom) FROM tbld) b WHERE a.bid=b.id ORDER BY a.bid)
            SELECT geom FROM tblf;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL
```

```
SELECT ST_RaysInGridPolygons(geom) geom FROM <grid_polygons>
```

You should get a result like the one in my picture.

[image]

Picture

(-: FOGS :-)

Comment: I actually want to group the ones that are parallel together. And I actually got my code to work as desired, I just removed the buffer and envelop, I made the the lines on the cells as is, then after I had the lines I extended them out to the length I wanted. The reason I want to group the parallel ones together is because 1. I want to join those in the group that intersect, and 2. this is all part of a test to determine which group is the winner, I will only keep one group. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I don't think I understand you, but if you know the azimuth, you can pick out the lines you need, then try it yourself...

Comment: thats fine, thank you for this query, I'll test to see if it works better than what I have. would you happen to have a slick query to group all the lines together by azimuth?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/382116/120129